# Luaotfload: version mismatch

Tags: luatex, texlive, luaotfload

Compiling with LuaLaTeX and the recent update seems to produce some disturbance:

```
    ...
) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu2enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu2lmr.fd)
luaotfload | db : Version mismatch; expected 2.207, got 2.204
luaotfload | db : Force rebuild
```

I let the rebuild proceed for more than 40 minutes, and all my CPU got used up by this process and so i aborted the compilation.

I found this problem already in this [mailing list](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2013-July/033913.html). But

`luaotfload-tool --update --force -vv`

results in an error:

```
/usr/texbin/luaotfload-tool:1257: unfinished string near '"Fetching comparison between %s and %s, z'
```

I can't find any help on this. What to do??

(TeXLive2013, Mac OS X)

Comment: Delete the folders `fonts` and `names` in `~/.texlive2013/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic`. The database will be rebuilt with the next run.

Comment: ``unfinished string near`` -- which version of Luatex are you running? Also please post the output of ``luaotfload-tool --diagnose=files,permissions``.

Comment: Btw. the message ``force rebuild`` means that luaotfload is busy regenerating the database, so you should probably let it finish.

Comment: @phg: Even if you let it finish, the message will appear again with the next run and the compiling process seems almost endlessly. I faced the same problem and only the advice from my first comment worked.

Comment: @thorsten-donig that would indicate that you lack write permissions in the cache directory, which is weird. What does ``--diagnose=files,permissions`` report for you?

Comment: @phg: Of course I have writing permissions in my own home directory and in the cache folder. Fact is that rebuilding of the database will be tried again and again.

Comment: @thorsten-donig fixed in next luaotfload. (Which incidentally will also trigger an auto-rebuild due to a new db version.)

Comment: For me the solution was to remove the directories under `~/Library/texlive`.  In my set-up everything here was automatically generated.  In particular, this removed the cache file, which was then successfully built on the next run.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, this made the rebuild go away, but I get several warnings: `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape EU2/AdobeCaslonPro(0)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU2/AdobeCaslonPro(0)/m/n' instead on input line 114.` and so on, and the fonts get substituted by other typefaces..

Comment: Are you sure you have the fonts?

Comment: yes because it worked fine before the TexLive Update. it's still the same font, only that they are suddenly in bold, plus the the small caps are not available. Also everything compiles fine under XeLaTeX.

Comment: on mac delete the folders fonts and names in `~/Library/texlive/2013/texmf-var/luatex-cache`(comment on the comment from @ThorstenDonig)

Answer (score 4):

Hm, I ran into the same issue. 
`~/.texlive2013/` does not exist on my Mac OS X (Snow Leopard)

FWIW there are

`/private/var/db/receipts/org.tug.mactex.texlive2013.bom`   and
`/private/var/db/receipts/org.tug.mactex.texlive2013.plist`

`luaotfload-tool --diagnose=files`, permissions    gives

```
/usr/texbin/luaotfload-tool:1257: unfinished string near '"Fetching comparison between %s and %s, z'
```

Im using beta-0.76:

This is `LuaTeX`, Version `beta-0.76.0-2013061817`  (TeX Live 2013) (rev 4627)

but I'm surprised, `luatex --version` in the terminal gives 
This is `LuaTeX`, Version `beta-0.70.2-2012122916` (TeX Live 2012/MacPorts 2012_5)

I changed the Path, so `luaotfload-tool --update` in `/usr/texbin` was invoked with configuration of `texlive2013` - with this recreation of the db was possible. Now I ran into `TeX capacity exceeded`, but I think this is another problem.

I guess, my `luaotfload-tool` found some configuration from `texlive2012`, after changing the PATH it was possible to update the db of `LuaLaTeX` from command line.

Comment: ``beta-0.70.2-2012122916`` -- I suspected as much since luaotfload uses Lua 5.2 syntax nowadays which Luatex < 0.75 cannot parse. Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here, but could you elaborate how and where to you changed your PATH? (I'm not a bash-type-of-TeXist..) Thanks!

Comment: on mac the settings / cache folders lives in `~/Library/texlive/`(see above my comment on the comment from @ThorstenDonig)

Answer (score 4):

On OS X, the files of `luaotfload` are written to `~/Library/texlive/2013/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic`

So, as I had this very problem, I did

```
% cd ~/Library/texlive/2013/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic
% rm -r fonts names
% luaotfload-tool --update --force -vv
luaotfload | util : Setting log level
luaotfload | util : Task completed successfully
luaotfload | db : Updating the font names database forcefully
luaotfload | db : Blacklisting "7" files and directories
luaotfload | db : Whitelisting "0" files
luaotfload | db : Scanning TEXMF fonts...
luaotfload | db : Scanning directory /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype
luaotfload | db : Scanning directory /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe
luaotfload | db : Scanning directory /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro
[…] 
luaotfload | db : Scanning directory /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/theleagueofmoveabletype
luaotfload | db : Scanning directory /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/theleagueofmoveabletype/raleway
luaotfload | db : Scanning OS fonts...
luaotfload | db : Searching in static system directories...
luaotfload | db : Scanning directory ~/Library/Fonts
luaotfload | db : Scanning directory /Library/Fonts
luaotfload | db : Scanning directory /System/Library/Fonts
luaotfload | db : No such directory: "/Network/Library/Fonts"; skipping.
luaotfload | db : Creating filename map
[…]
luaotfload | db : Font file "Times.dfont" already indexed (1315)
luaotfload | db : > old location: /System/Library/Fonts/Times.dfont
luaotfload | db : > new location: /System/Library/Fonts/Times.dfont
luaotfload | db : Scanned 4202 font files; 1166 new entries.
luaotfload | db : Rebuilt in 537530 ms
luaotfload | db : Fonts in the database: 1320
luaotfload | db : Font index saved
luaotfload | db : Text: ~/Library/texlive/2013/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.lua
luaotfload | db : Byte: ~/Library/texlive/2013/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc
luaotfload | util : Task completed successfully
```

That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

On ArchLinux (TexLive 2013), I solved this by deleting `~/.texlive/texmf-var/luatex-cache/`. Running LuaTeX after that gave the following warning:

```
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.
luaotfload | db : Font index saved)
```

But it did this (generating the db) in a matter of seconds. Previously I had the same `version mismatch` warning you reported, and it seemed to take forever (I ended up interrupting the process before completion after a few minutes...).

Hope this helps.