# 'Moderncv classic 1.5.1' lualatex compilation fails when using \itshape and awesome icons and sans font with MacTeX2013

Tags: fonts, luatex, moderncv, mactex, fontawesome

When compiling this tex code on SnowLeopard, MacTeX2013 with `lualatex test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % moderncv 1.5.1 version
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvicons{awesome}

\name{john}{doe}
\begin{document}
\itshape hello, world
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
[...]
! Font \EU2/lmss/m/sl/10.95=/Library/Fonts/Latin not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
M
l.7 \itshape
           hello, world
?
```

It compiles if I remove the `\itshape` command.

It compiles if I remove the `\moderncvicons{awesome}` command.

It compiles if I use `roman` instead of `sans`.

It compiles when using `xelatex` (but I don't want to regenerate the fontawesome font to get around [the UPM bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134121/fontawesome-icons-are-getting-too-big-using-xelatex)).

It compiles on ubuntu 12.10, TexLive2012.

It looks like to me that using `sans`,`\itshape` and `fontawesome` with `MacTex2013` is the combination that prevents lualatex from compiling and `\itshape` is the deciding factor.

Regarding the error message: could it be than somehow a bad Latin font got installed ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I tried your example and it works fine for me. Do you use an up to date MacTeX version?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I thought it was up-to-date but the package manager tells me it can fetch 25MB of data so I'll update my question once I run my tests with the updated MacTeX.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Once the update was completed I ran into this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126467/luaotfload-version-mismatch] problem when compiling but this http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135317/40910 answer solved my problems. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem solved with a software update

Comment: @egreg: I agree.